# Undeclared Identifiers in CBPeripheral Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, cbperipheral, bluno

Xcode 9.2 - - Objective C - - Bluno BLE

Hi, I am figuring out a piece of code where I encountered some errors, any help will be much appreciated!

[Here](https://github.com/timburks/iOSHeartRateMonitor/blob/master/HRM/HeartRateViewController.m) is the site with the original code.

Below is an extract of the code from line **224** to line **232**:

```
 if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString]]) {
    for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics) {
        // Read device name 
        if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CBUUIDDeviceNameString]]) {
            [aPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
            NSLog(@"Found a Device Name Characteristic");
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the code, I received these errors:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString'
>
> Use of undeclared identifier 'CBUUIDDeviceNameString'

Is there anything I am missing here? Thanks in advance!